# How set proxy headers in proxy.config.json file for angularcli project

Tags: proxy, angular-cli

I'm trying to set proxy headers for `angularcli`. Here's what I have so far in my `proxy.config.json` file:

```
"/api": {
    "target": "https://applications.str.coni.com/api",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
```

But I haven't had any luck so far, perhaps I'm missing something (probably in another file). Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Formatted code, rephrased the question

Comment: You can modify both request and response headers and request is easy with the code from @Ale

Answer (score 34):

Angular-cli uses `http-proxy-middleware` https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

there is an option called `headers` that you can use: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-option

example:

```
"/api":
  {
    "target": "https://applications.str.coni.com/api",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {"host":"www.example.org"}
  }
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answers your question, please accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can modify both request and response headers and request is easy with the code from @AhmedMusallam answer but for response headers you'll need to change file to *proxy.config.js* and modify proxy config file to look like this:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api": {
      "target": "https://applications.str.coni.com/api",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "onProxyRes": function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization';
      },
    },
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: This onProxyRes  function doesn't get triggered in proxy.conf.js file.Is there anything have to be added.

Comment: sadly this not works for me [more](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17910)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular CLI v13 and its uses bypass interceptor for modifying the headers.

sample code of proxy config put it in a file and name it proxy.conf.js (you can choose any suitable name of the file as you like)

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
    "/api/proxy": {
        "target": "http://localhost:80",
        "secure": false,
        "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
            if (req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
                console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request.");
                return "/index.html";
            }
            req.headers["X-Custom-Header"] = "yes"; // adding oe setting header
            res.removeHeader('X-Header-Name'); //removing header
        }
    }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

and then simply run serve command with proxy.

```
ng serve -proxy-config proxy.conf.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this slightly changed with Angular 16+ with Vite (instead of webpack).

```
const setHeader = (proxyReq) => {
  proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'myToken');
};

export default [
{
    context: ['/api'],
    target: `https://localhost}`,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    configure: (proxy) => {
        proxy. On('proxyRes', setHeader);
    }
},
```