# How to remove X-Powered-By header from proxy-conf.js file in angular cli project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to remove `x-powered-by` header from response headers in angular cli project.As there is no direct access for express, so how can we remove header from all request's response header.
I tried following -

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
 {
   context: [
     '/'
   ],
   secure: false,
   bypass: function (req, res) {
     res.removeHeader('x-powered-by');
   }
 }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

But it worked only for first request, for all other request it didn't work.

I tried following as well but the function doesn't get triggered -

```
 const PROXY_CONFIG = [
 {
   context: [
     '/'
   ],
   secure: false,
   onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
     delete proxyRes.headers['x-powered-by']; 
   }
 }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I referred following links -

[Angular: add custom HTTP response headers to dev `ng serve`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266224/angular-add-custom-http-response-headers-to-dev-ng-serve)

[How set proxy headers in proxy.config.json file for angularcli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591539/how-set-proxy-headers-in-proxy-config-json-file-for-angularcli-project)

Comment: i am facing similar issue , did you find a solution for this, i am trying it using interceptors,  
 This is still not working......(event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          event = event.clone({
            headers: event.headers.delete('x-aspnet-version')
              .delete('x-powered-by')
          });
          return event;
        }

Comment: I think you can do that easily using hemlet.js on express side.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove existing header in Interceptors.

```
 if (!req.headers.has('X-Powered-By')) {
 req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.delete('X-Powered-By','xxxxx') });
```

To Check the current value of the header.

```
req.headers.get('Accept')
```

Comment: It is a response header, i think we would need to handle it when sending response right.

Comment: yes but if you didnt had accept to the response header so when fetching it with angular, interceptions can be used for the same task.

Comment: i am trying to do same , but it is not working 
          event = event.clone({
            headers: event.headers.delete('x-aspnet-version').delete('x-powered-by')
          });

Comment: You are doing it wrong   req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.delete(''x-powered-by','x-aspnet-version') });

Comment: i had tried both dint work, finally removed it using server settings to remove headers.

Answer (score 0):

It does work for the proxies correctly. So for all the request it was resolved by adding it on express side. Used helmetjs.

```
const helmet = require('helmet')

app.use(helmet())
app.disable('x-powered-by')
```